# android My applicaiton run fine in debug mode but not working on runmode ?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, wsdl

I call wdsl service and xmlparsing its running fine in debug mode but not working on runmode. Orderid tag my call xml tag coming empty runmode but in debug mode its coming fill.

Comment: Facing same situation on my side. Did you fix that?